# How can I use async method inside sync method

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, async-await

I have a sync method as below:

```
public ActionResult Insert([FromBody] Model model) { }
```

and I also have an async method:

```
_myMethodAsync();
```

My async method returns `int`.
If I do like this I have to edit everything

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Insert(...){
...
await _myMethodAsync();
...
}
```

Normally when I add without await I get wrong results.

```
public ActionResult Insert([FromBody] Model model)
{
    //...
    _myMethodAsync();
    //...
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c

Comment: Just do `_myMethodAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Answer (score 1):

Call it with `await`. The compiler will instruct you on what to do next: change `Insert` to an `async` method and change its result type from `ActionResult` to `Task<ActionResult>`.

Comment: I can't . because if i do what you say i have to edit everything

Comment: @CelalSunnetci: And why does that stop you?

Comment: there is an easier option